# Server and client are python scripts, are there a way to synchronize server to client time without changing system dates anywere?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timezone

I'm using time and datetime modules in server and in client scripts. When I am receiving data that contains date from server - it is wrong and different to client because of wrong timezone and wrong time on server.
How to deal with it and what is the best way to deal with it?
Thanks

Comment: The best aproach is to use NTP to sincronize the time and date on your servers.

Comment: And if I add restrictions like 
1. no additional packages on server and 
2. server and client are connected over ssh commands and nothing else.  Then the answer will be only play with time deltas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either convert the time to the time zone of the client, or show the time zone. I e, for a client in Warsaw show

"2015-05-14 11:40" *or* "2015-05-14 09:40 GMT" or similar.

Which one you want depends a lot on what data it is you are showing.

How to figure out the client timezone is a long topic that probably is covered elsewhere here, and that again depends on the application. You can convert it with Javascript, or have a setting, or make a guess based on countr and IP address, etc. Loads of options.

Comment: Thanx. However this wouldn't help if time on client and on server is wrong and differs not only in timezone but, for example, in ten minutes. In this case I have to use timedeltas, as I understand, right?

Comment: If the time on the server is wrong, you need to correct that time. That's the only solution, honestly.